# Javascript Create XML DOM - The Node Object

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, typescript

I have a simple question:
**How can I create a new Node from scratch?**

Here is my situation:

I need to build an XML Structure from an object list.

I have a method `ToElement` on each control ( Textbox, combobox, ...) and I want this method to return a **XML DOM Node object** to use the [appendChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp) and his parent.

I'm not able to find how to create a Node object from scratch I know that I can use an `XMLDocument.createElement` but this method return an
**HTMLElement** and you can't use appendChild with this kind of element.

```
nodeObject.appendChild(HTMLelement) //** Not Working**
```

Is there a way to convert an HTMLElement to a Node ?
The only way that I found to create an element it's from a XMLDocument:

```
XMLDocument.createElement // (Return a new HTMLElement)
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp Take a look at this site.

Comment: in nodeObject.appendChild(HTMLelement) what is nodeObject ??

Comment: @Matteo Rubini http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_node.asp 
and Geno Diaz I already look at it the problem with this it's returning an "HTMLElement" and my problem is that i have controls named "Label" , "Html", "Textbox" and if i'm using document.createElement("Html") the parser will think that i want to create the <html> from a html page

Comment: A `<foo>` is an _Element_ and an _Element_ is a _Node_, other node types are _text, comment, doctype, etc_. You probably do want an _Element_. What specifically about `appendChild` isn't working? You may need to check that the _#document_ used to _createElement_ is the _#document_ you're trying to append it too, and if that is impossible, `foo = targetDoc.importNode(elem); targetDoc.appendChild(foo);`

Comment: But you cant create a new element with tag HTML or BODY ....

Comment: @MatteoRubini sure you can. You can even replace the current document's `<body>`. Replacing the current document's `<html>` is less likely to work though as it is `document.documentElement`, but that doesn't stop you creating them

Answer (score 0):

1. Creating a new XML DOM object

   var xmlDoc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, "books");

The first argument can contain the namespace URI of the document to be created, if the document belongs to one.

([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createDocument))